# Why doesn't my Numpy mask work with OpenCV bitwiseAnd()?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

To this code:

```
mask = np.zeros((2464, 2464), dtype='uint8')
cv2.circle(mask, (1232, 1232), 1100, 255, -1)

img = cv2.imread(IMAGES[0])
img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call
last) <ipython-input-20-71dc0dfb0a3f> in <module>
      1 example = cv2.imread(IMAGES[0])
      2 
----> 3 example = cv2.bitwise_and(example, example, mask=mask)
      4 plt.imshow(example)

error: OpenCV(4.2.0)
C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:250:
error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) &&
_mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'
```

Doesn't OpenCV expect uint8 as mask data type like I provided?

Comment: Could you provide us with the image. Maybe the it is the size assertion error.

Comment: The image shape was correct. I did not realize that my notebook directory was different than where I worked before. So, the img type was None.

Comment: I am confused, how can an image have a shape of `(2464, 2464)` and be `None` at the same time. The assertion error is thrown most likely because your image is empty, hence the shape of it does not match the shape of the mask.

Comment: The shape of the image in the intended path was correct. img object was empty because the entered path was wrong.

Comment: I see. We both are correct. I am just explaining why the assertion error was thrown. You are explaining the root cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error. The problem was that my path (IMAGES[0]) was wrong. However, I just want to mention that passing dtype='uint8' is **necessary**. It gives the same error otherwise.